# SQL Server 2005 varchar with data ddmmyyyy to datetime format

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime

I have a column finish date in my application db table JOB whose data type is `varchar(16)` (quite strange) but this column stores date values in wayward formats like `yyyyddmm` (e.g.- 19841511), `yyyymmdd` (e.g.- 19841215), `ddmmyyyy` (e.g.- 01012007).

I just want the data to be converted to one uniform date time format which is the default date time format of SQL Server 2005 which is

```
yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.000
```

Can you guys please help me sort this issue out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how are you going to determine values like `20121001` is what date ?

Comment: Well,assuming it is 01'Oct 2012 , don't have a choice to find if that's right or wrong, that is why I said all sorts of wayward formats conversion to 1 uniform date time field, let the query figure that out.

Comment: lovely, the dates are not formatted correctly at all. I hope you know which ones are formatted which way. :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, I hope you have a systemic method to knowing which row is stored which way, because `DATETIME` does not have a default format and your strings are stored in the wrong format...*as in that format does not exist* in SQL. Without outside help, SQL has no way of knowing.

- There is no date that is formatted `YYYY-DD-MM`. Looks like custom work. :/
- VARCHAR(16) also means you do not have any seconds in your `DATETIME` format...yay! :(

Unless you know beforehand which dates are formatted what, it is going to be near impossible to sort this out without going back to the source that is publishing these "dates".

```
SELECT CASE WHEN ISDATE('19841511') = 0
        THEN  SUBSTRING('19841511', 1, 4) + '-'  --YEAR
            + SUBSTRING('19841511', 7, 2) + '-'  -- MONTH
            + SUBSTRING('19841511', 5, 2) END AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
     , CASE WHEN ISDATE('01012007') = 0
        THEN SUBSTRING('01012007', 5, 4) + '-' --YEAR
            + SUBSTRING('01012007', 3, 2) + '-' --MONTH
            + SUBSTRING('01012007', 1, 2) END AS [YYYY-MM-DD]
```

Note the difference in the two formats...and that both formats are not stored in a date format that SQL Server recognizes.

- `DATETIME2` does use the default format you are looking for YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss[.fractional seconds]

Hope this at least gets you towards the right answer!